# Windows Phone 8 background task

Tags: networking, background, windows-phone-8, task

Is there a way to keep internet connection alive while application is switched to another task, such as PhotoChooserTask or ShareStatusTask? I've already seen background agents, but they doesn't meet my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Launching a task is pretty much the same as launching another application: your own application gets turned off and stops running. Therefore, it isn't possible to keep open the existing network connections, nor to do any kind of background processing.

Comment: What about location-tracking in the background? Will it disconnect right after switching the task? My app is using location-tracking so it might be possible to implement it that way.

Comment: @iMaks Using the GeoLocator, it may indeed be possible. Worth a try! http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp8-new-location-apis--part-2-location-tracking-and-background-location-tracking `HttpWebRequest` is included in the list of APIs you can use from the background: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941(v=vs.105).aspx